# How to change Archive link url in Exrpession Engine

Tags: php, codeigniter

Expression engine archive is showing link in this manner eg.

```
    {exp:channel:month_links channel="news" limit="50"}
    {month}, {year}<br>
    {/exp:channel:month_links}
```

`http://www.example.com/news/archives/2015/09`

how to change it like in this way

`http://www.example.com/news/archives/2015/9`

Comment: This *could* be done with an .htaccess rule utilizing `mod_rewrite` and `mod_proxy`, but to break a standard for date formatting seems strange, and too much work/maintenance. You'd have to live in an obscure (no offense!) country that has a quirky date format.

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately not possible with ExpressionEngine's default `month_links` functionality.

Your options are:

```
{month} - Month, long format: September

{month_num} - Month, numeric: 09

{month_short} - Month, short format: Sep
```

[EE archive_month_links documentation](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/archive_month_links.html#month)

Hope this helps you.